Why are tensor product surfaces called tensor product surfaces?
This has been asked before without a good answer.
The kinds of surfaces I know which are referred to as product surfaces seem to be globally parametrizable 2D manifolds, like Coons  patches, swept surfaces, NURBS/bezier patches...
I.e. any 2-manifold where one can find a global bijection from the manifold to a 2D subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Or symbolically
$S(u, v) = (X(u, v), Y(u, v), Z(u,v))$
Where $\{(u,v)\}$ is a compact set of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $S$ is bijective.
The tensor product is an operation that combines vectors into a new object, which is essentially just an ordered pair of the the vectors (or a matrix depending ont he representation one is using).
I fail to see the connection between tensors and globally parametrizable surfaces.

A mere bijection won't in general preserve any topological information. Can you please quote the definition from where you saw "tensor product surfaces" mentioned?

This resource gives one possible definition:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/tensor-product-surface

Interesting how all your examples were misspelled. What you're calling swept surfaces is a generalization of ruled surfaces, and I could see referring to that construction as a product construction. But certainly not any surface that is globally parametrized by one patch.

I don't know if all globally parametrizable surfaces are tensor surfaces, all I know is that all globally parametrizable surfaces I know of are referred to as tensor surfaces

You seem to have extremely narrow experience with surfaces and differential geometry. The definition you linked seems to have a very limited and discrete scope. In particular, it refers explicitly to bivariate polynomials and products.  I don’t know how you extrapolated from that.
